# difference between two methods of assigning a variable Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I am pretty new to vba and I don't get why these two statement don't return the same result:

1. `If myValue > 400 Then Range("F" & i).Value = myValue + 10`
2. `If myValue > 400 Then myValue = myValue + 10`

actually, the first now does its job very well that is to add 10 to the value in Range "F" but the second one just shows it adds 10 to myvalue in "Locals" Window but not in the Range F. There is no error whatsoever picked by VBA!
Thank you for your advice

Comment: Why would you expect the second statement to have any affect at all on `Fi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between your two statements is where you are assigning the value. In the first, you are telling Excel to set the **value of the range** to myValue + 10. In the second, you are telling Excel to set the **value of myValue** to myValue + 10. myValue is a variable declared in your VBA. It is not a cell in your spreadsheet.